How to create a column check with a filter condition in PanderaPolars / PanderaPandas?
I am trying to use Pandera library to define data quality checks on a dataset.
The dataset is loaded as polars dataframe and PanderaPolars is being used to define the checks.
For some column checks, we require a joint condition to be set on multiple columns.
For example

check that column A is not null when that column B = "unit_price"
check that column C = column D + column E
compute correlation between column F and column G is bigger than 0.5

using a file having BUY_SELL (str, B or S), PRODUCT_TYPE (str, REV or XX) , QUANTITY (float)
I would like to define the following check:

when PRODUCT_TYPE = "REV" and BUY_SELL = "B", check if QUANTITY > 10

I tried to come up with 2 custom checks as per below, using Pandas (not Polars) but they are not working as expected. In Polars I was not able to write something equivalent as it seems not to have the lambda available
import pandera as pa
import pandas as pd
import warnings

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')


check_quantity_grouped = pa.Check(
                        lambda g: g[(True, "B")] > 10,
                            groupby=lambda df: (
                            df.assign(product_type_rev=lambda d: d["PRODUCT_TYPE"] == "REV")
                            .groupby(["product_type_rev", "BUY_SELL"])
                            )
                        ,ignore_na=True,raise_warning=False, error="trade quantity, when product_type = REV and BUY_SELL = B, is less than 10"
                        )

check_quantity_filter = pa.Check(
                        lambda df: df[(df['PRODUCT_TYPE'] == 'REV') & (df['BUY_SELL'] == 'B')] > 10
                        ,ignore_na=True,raise_warning=False
                        )


schema = pa.DataFrameSchema({

    "QUANTITY": pa.Column(float, [check_quantity_filter, check_quantity_grouped], nullable=True)

})


try:
    schema(df, lazy=True)
except pa.errors.SchemaErrors as exc:
    filtered_df = df[df.index.isin(exc.failure_cases["index"])]
    failures = exc.failure_cases
print(f"filtered df:\n{filtered_df}")
print(failures)

My question is whether more complicated check such as the ones listed above are possible in Pandera (Polars ideally but if not in Pandas as well)

I hadn't heard of pandera before but in looking at their README, they don't seem to have documentation on their polars support. Fortunately they have some tests on polars, does this help?

I agree, I think it's still recent and documentation will be enriched soon. There is this link https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polars.html where there is some initial documentation

I've not used Pandera before, so it's possible this could be improved.
According to these examples: https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/polars.html#dataframe-level-checks
You define a function that is passed data which contains a .lazyframe where you can run your Polars code.
df = pl.read_csv(b"""
PRODUCT_TYPE,BUY_SELL,QUANTITY
ABC,D,13
REV,B,11
REV,B,5
REV,B,12
REV,C,9
""".strip())

Your desired logic appears to be:
df.with_columns(
    pl.when(pl.col.PRODUCT_TYPE == "REV", pl.col.BUY_SELL == "B")
      .then(pl.col.QUANTITY > 10)
      .otherwise(True)
)

shape: (5, 3)
┌──────────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ PRODUCT_TYPE ┆ BUY_SELL ┆ QUANTITY │
│ ---          ┆ ---      ┆ ---      │
│ str          ┆ str      ┆ bool     │
╞══════════════╪══════════╪══════════╡
│ ABC          ┆ D        ┆ true     │
│ REV          ┆ B        ┆ true     │
│ REV          ┆ B        ┆ false    │
│ REV          ┆ B        ┆ true     │
│ REV          ┆ C        ┆ true     │
└──────────────┴──────────┴──────────┘

Put into Pandera:
import polars as pl
import pandera.polars as pa
from   pandera.polars import PolarsData

df = pl.read_csv(b"""
PRODUCT_TYPE,BUY_SELL,QUANTITY
ABC,D,13
REV,B,11
REV,B,5
REV,B,12
REV,C,9
""".strip())

def check_quantity_filter(data: PolarsData) -> pl.LazyFrame:
    return data.lazyframe.select(
        pl.when(pl.col.PRODUCT_TYPE == "REV", pl.col.BUY_SELL == "B")
          .then(pl.col.QUANTITY > 10)
          .otherwise(True)
    )

schema = pa.DataFrameSchema({
    "QUANTITY": pa.Column(float, checks=[pa.Check(check_quantity_filter)], nullable=True)
})

try:
    schema(df, lazy=True)
except pa.errors.SchemaErrors as exc:
    failures = exc.failure_cases
    print(failures)

It gives:
shape: (2, 6)
┌──────────────┬────────────────┬──────────┬───────────────────────┬──────────────┬───────┐
│ failure_case ┆ schema_context ┆ column   ┆ check                 ┆ check_number ┆ index │
│ ---          ┆ ---            ┆ ---      ┆ ---                   ┆ ---          ┆ ---   │
│ str          ┆ str            ┆ str      ┆ str                   ┆ i32          ┆ i32   │
╞══════════════╪════════════════╪══════════╪═══════════════════════╪══════════════╪═══════╡
│ Int64        ┆ Column         ┆ QUANTITY ┆ dtype('Float64')      ┆ null         ┆ null  │
│ 5            ┆ Column         ┆ QUANTITY ┆ check_quantity_filter ┆ 0            ┆ 2     │
└──────────────┴────────────────┴──────────┴───────────────────────┴──────────────┴───────┘

